# How many applications can be signed with single key?

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

Have checked out 
https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

How many applications I can sign with this registration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has much as you want

Answer (score 0):

That's not completely true. When I sign my apps I get an email from BlackBerry saying:

A code signing request completed successfully for client 'YourClientIDHere'.  The client has 2147483634 request(s) left.

This is a large number of signings you can do but not technically as much as you want.